# Path Tracing in Android

Tags: android

i want to add such feature in my Application that App will recognize letters, numbers etc tracing (with finger).

For Example if i want to define path for 'A', then at first i need to define the Nodes to which the child will merge through drawing straight line, but i don't know that how to define path for each object.

Kindly give your suggestions or refer me helping material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really take a look at the [FingerPaint](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html) tutorial in the API demos provided by the SDK.

You can use blinking nodes to indicate the next point, so that the kid can trace the letter. Once the touch coordinates come within 1 centimeter range of the destination blinking node, the next node should blink/glow etc. You can store the list of nodes and tracing information in a db.

Comment: thanks for your help, tell me just one thing that how we can determine that kid is going right or wrong on the Path, e.g there are many paths to merge two nodes but right one is the Straight Path.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think you should use bearings, i.e, angles made wrt the vertical. You should keep a bearing tolerance, if the finger goes out of the required angle tolerance, you can use some kind of animating arrows indicating the correct direction.

Comment: Thanks a Lot, your answer given me a Good Idea.